# "C2593: operator = is ambiguous" when populating std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::map` I'm trying to initialize with an initialization list. I do this in two places, in two different ways. The first one works, while the other one causes the error mentioned in the title.

Here's the one that works:

```
void foo() {
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> fooMap =
    {
        { "First", "ABC" },
        { "Second", "DEF" }
    };
}
```

While this one does not:

```
class Bar {
    public:
        Bar();
    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::string> barMap;
};

Bar::Bar() {
    barMap = { // <-- this is the error line
        { "First", "ABC" },
        { "Second", "DEF" }
    };
}
```

Why do I get the error when trying to initialize the class member, while the static map works? At the moment, I can populate the member by first creating a local variable and then swapping it with the member like this:

```
Bar::Bar() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> tmpMap = {
        { "First", "ABC" },
        { "Second", "DEF" }
    };

    barMap.swap(tmpMap);
}
```

However, this feels rather counter-intuitive compared to just populating the member directly.

---

EDIT: [Here's the compiler output.](http://pastebin.com/wycmCJuG)

Comment: This compiles on ideone: http://ideone.com/OkXujD

Comment: @manabreak It seems it is a compiler bug. Please show the full error message.

Comment: It works on GCC 4.7.2.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Not an answer, bud I'd write: `Bar::Bar():barMap{{ "First", "ABC" },{ "Second", "DEF" }} {}`

Comment: Try to initialize barMap in the initalizer list:

Comment: @JohnZwinck Visual Studio 2013. I'll update the question with the compiler output asap.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/az0JSm). I guess your compiler is broken. Does it work if you initialise it in the constructor's initialiser list, or the member declaration, rather than reassigning it in the constructor body?

Comment: @MikeSeymour It seems to work in the constructor's initializer list.

Comment: @manabreak: There's your workaround then. That's a better way to initialise a member in any case.

Comment: I bet it is VC++. I am suffering it at work.

Comment: Note that the first one is *initialization* and the second one is *assignment*. The C++11 standard committee worked very hard to try and get the second one to work (C++03 had nothing at all like that).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in your compilers overload resolution mechanism - or its standard library implementation. 
Overload resolution clearly states in [over.ics.rank]/3 that

> — List-initialization sequence `L1` is a better conversion sequence than
>   list-initialization sequence `L2` if `L1` converts to
>   `std::initializer_list<X>` for some `X` and `L2` does not.

Here, `X` is `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`. `L1` converts your list to the parameter of

```
map& operator=( std::initializer_list<value_type> ilist );
```

Whilst `L2` converts the list to one of the following functions' parameters:

```
map& operator=( map&& other );
map& operator=( const map& other );
```

Which clearly aren't `initializer_list`s.

---

You could try to use

```
barMap = decltype(barMap){
    { "First", "ABC" },
    { "Second", "DEF" }
};
```

Which should select the move-assignment operator ([Demo with VC++](http://rextester.com/GIG33127)). The temporary should also be optimized away according to copy elision.

Comment: Could you dumb it down for me? I still don't understand why it doesn't work when trying to re-assign.

Comment: @manabreak I actually added a possible workaround that works with rextesters vc++.