# Pure virtual function overridden by inherited class C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, c++11

Can a pure virtual function (i.e one that has = 0 on the end) be overridden by an inherited class with a constant pure virtual function and still get called?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct cBaseClass {
    virtual void VirtualFunction () = 0;
};

struct cInheritedClass : cBaseClass {
    virtual void VirtualFunction () const {
        printf ("I'm a constant virtual function that"
                " overrided a pure virtual function!\n");
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    cBaseClass *Foo = new cInheritedClass;
    Foo->VirtualFunction ();
}
```

The last line should result in cInheritedClass::VirtualFunction being called, not cBaseClass::VirtualFunction. I'm hoping that a constant function is just a compiler directive to make sure nothing inside the class gets written too and doesn't effect inheritance. I'm using this in my level class for some of the collision routines, where it would be nice to specify if the function can modify the class on a per Object/Class basis.

Comment: Have you tried to execute this code?

Comment: You dont need virtual keyword if this has not be inherited by other sub classes

Comment: Your overriding function is not pure.

Comment: @nvoigt: [That is obviously not always true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26524503/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not saying the compiler is the ultimate, standard-implementing, bug-free truth. I'm just saying that posting on the internet *without* testing it with your own compiler does not make sense.

Comment: @nvoigt: Well, that's not what you said. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const` and `volatile` qualifiers do form part of the function's signature, so a `const` function won't override a non-`const` one. My compiler rejects your code for this reason:

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘cInheritedClass’
note:  because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘cInheritedClass’:
note:  virtual void cBaseClass::VirtualFunction()
```

In C++11 or later, you can declare that the function should be an override:

```
void VirtualFunction () const override // "virtual" is optional when overriding
```

to get better diagnostics even if you don't try to instantiate the class:

```
error: ‘virtual void cInheritedClass::VirtualFunction() const’ marked override, but does not override
```